# Ler arquivo e criar loop

Tags: javascript, loop

Eu tenho um arquivo txt com vários nomes em coluna:

> ```
> Nome 01
> Nome 02
> Nome 03...
> ```

No arquivos .js eu preciso criar um loop para que cada nome seja lido e carregado para uma variável para que seja feito os cálculos e salvo em um arquivo com o nome individual.

A parte dos cálculos já está feita, mas eu não consigo ler o arquivo txt e criar o loop.

O que eu tenho neste momento é:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
d3 = require("d3"),
mkdirp = require("mkdirp");

fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data){
    var linhas = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    linhas.forEach(function(linha){

var flightId = "linha", 


      mkdirp("data", function(err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        else {
          fs.writeFile("data/" + flightId + ".tsv", csvFormated);
          fs.writeFile("data/data.geojson", JSON.stringify(geojson));
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Flight data not found");
    }
  });
```

Comment: amigo dá uma olhada nesse artigo https://codigosimples.net/2016/04/25/ler-um-arquivo-local-usando-html5-e-javascript/

Comment: Quase isto, mas eu preciso rodar o java através do node. Obrigado Maycon

Comment: Consegui fazer....

var flightId = linha,